# How to call an ajax loading spinner on a page that renders no ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
// Loading Spinner in javascript file

function start_spinner() {
    ajaxDone= false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!ajaxDone) $(".loading").show();
    }, 1500);
}

function stop_spinner() {
    ajaxDone=true;
    $(".loading").hide();
}

$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI).ajaxStop($.unblockUI);

    var ajaxDone;
    // show spinner on AJAX start
    $(document).ajaxStart(start_spinner).ajaxSuccess(stop_spinner).ajaxError(stop_spinner);
```

Calling this in .html.erb file

```
<script>
      function start_spinner(){
          $('#Register').onclick();
 }
</script>
```

The loading spinner works correctly for pages that load ajax but how do I call the spinner when no ajax is present??

Thanks

Comment: Are you making a cross domain ajax call?